# How can I get count of sql query using WHERE clause ( SQL Server )

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that can return the leaveID , Id and day .

```
select DAY,employeeId,(select lv.EmployeeId 
from employee_Leaves lv
where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) as Leave
from employee_c c,holiday hl,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+2, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+2, -1)) 
where DATENAME(DD, Weekday) IN (select dayId+1 from days) and Date not between hl.startDate and hl.endDate and c.isActive=1 order by employeeID,DAY
```

the output of this query is something like this:

[image]

What I'm searching for is , return the count of the leaveID ( where LeaveID is null ) depending on the employee.

I suppose that the count of leaveID for employee `1` that have NULL values is `19` and `25` for the employee 2.

So , the result expected should be something like this :

```
employeeId    leavecount

    1             19
    2             25
```

I have tried this query , but it returns the count of all leaves for the all employees , what I need is the leavecount for every employee.

```
    select count(*) from (select (select lv.EmployeeId from employee_Leaves lv where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) as leaveID from employee_c c,holiday hl,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+1, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+1, -1))
where DATENAME(DD, Weekday) IN (select dayId+1 from days) and Date not between hl.startDate and hl.endDate and c.isActive=1 ) sc
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Evolve - stop using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). And stop cramming your code together. Develop GOOD habits.

Comment: I'm still beginner with SQL Server.

Comment: I don't get it: you are a beginner in SQL Server but not in other languages? In no programming language is it right to cram code together. And if you are new to SQL, where did you pick up the `,` cross-join from?

Comment: I will try to improve my code next time , thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by on your result to have your desired output:

```
select employeeid , count(*) from 
(
    select DAY,employeeId,(select lv.EmployeeId 
    from employee_Leaves lv
    where Date between lv.start_date and lv.end_date and lv.EmployeeId=c.employeeId and c.isActive=1) as Leave
    from employee_c c,holiday hl,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+2, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST('2021-01-01' AS datetime))+2, -1)) 
    where DATENAME(DD, Weekday) IN (select dayId+1 from days) and Date not between hl.startDate and hl.endDate and c.isActive=1 
) t
where leave is null
group by employeeid
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select employeeId,
       sum(case when leaveID is null then 1 else 0 end)
from employee_leave el
group by employeeId;
```

Comment: For what query I should use the conditional aggregation ( the first or the second )?

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 . . . This query should provide the answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you , but not exactly what I'm searching for , the first answer giving the expected result ...